# a problem with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to demonstrate that all the matrices $n*m$ with elements in K and $rank \le 1 $ are in the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2\\...\\ a_m \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & ... & b_n \end{pmatrix} $$  with $a_1, a_2,...a_m, b_1 , b_2, ..., b_n  \in  K $

My attempt is:

A matrix $n*m$ with $rank \le 1 $ can be reduced to a row vector or a column vector through a series of elementary operations with its rows and columns.

Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, but let me present you another interpretation of $\mathrm{rank}(M)\leq 1$:

It also means that the columns of the matrix span a subspace of at most dimension $1$, so all the columns are multiples of a single vector $\vec a=(a_1\ a_2\; \cdots\; a_m)^\top$. The factor by which each columns is a multiple of $\vec a$ are collected in your row-vector $\vec b=(b_1\;b_2\;\cdots\;b_n)$. Thats basically what your construction expresses: constructing a matrix where column $i$ is a $\vec a$ times $b_i$.

Comment: $ (b_1 \vec a \  \   b_2 \vec a  \  \ ..... \ \  b_n \vec a)$